# Как подключить два компьютера в один локальный репозиторий?

Tags: git

Работаем на Adnroid Studio. Сперва хотели залить на репозиторий `GitHub`, но потом передумали. Устанавили `git` на оба компа, теперь не можем друг с другом соединить? Может кто знает подскажите, как правильно сделать или может есть статьи именно по нашей проблеме...

Comment: Я так понимаю, что каждый делал свое и теперь у топикастера, условно говоря, проблема сделать из двух разных файлов один. А он хочет, чтобы за него это сделала программа. Но так не будет. Или будет, но криво. Сделайте сначала ручками все.

Comment: Нет - нет вы неправильно поняли, проект у меня, теперь он должен подключиться!

Comment: Сделайте на одной машине сервер Git и подключайтесь к нему.

Comment: Я так и понял, что нужно сделать одного сервером другого клиентом. Вопрос: Как?

Comment: прошу прощения, но я один не понимаю, причем тут теги `android`, `java`?

Comment: Android Studio подключаем - поэтому Android! А Java - вы тут правы!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вопрос решается настройкой git сервера на вашем компьютере. Но если у вас возникает вопрос об этом - то лучше все же воспользоваться одним из облачных репозиториев.

Как вы и сами сказали - например https://github.com

Если же нужен приватный репозиторий и не хочется платить за это, то можно воспользоваться https://bitbucket.org или аналогичным.

Думаю это будет проще и быстрей чем установка, настройка и администрирование своего личного git сервера. Да и проблем с подключением не должно быть.

Answer (score 2):

git на 2 компа решается создание bare-репозитория, к которому есть файловый доступ на запись с обоих рабочих мест (ssh на linux или общий доступ к папке на windows).
Все делается за 2 минут по манам.